# Get browser resolution on page load

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to get the Resolution of my browser at Page_Load event. What I have done is to call width() and height() inside  $(document).ready function and store the values in hidden fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= hdnResolutionX.ClientID %>").val($(window).width());
        $("#<%= hdnResolutionY.ClientID %>").val($(window).height());
});
```

My problem is that I am getting my values after postback.... How can I do this?

Comment: After the page is loaded, ASP.NET is out of the game. You will not be able to work on it, after your page has loaded.#

Comment: @SLaks Yes, it does, but you can only read them AFTER postback, which does not seem to satisfy OP.

Comment: @bash.d: You're right; I missed that line.